# best way to say the 24 hour time

Tags: time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should one say times aloud in 24-hour notation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35006/how-should-one-say-times-aloud-in-24-hour-notation)

Which words can be used to say time in 24 hour format? If, for instance, for 4:00 one might say "four o'clock", is it also correct to say "sixteen o'clock" for 16:00? Is it different for a casual conversation and for a presentation of some kind? It is also probably different for US and UK, and maybe for Europe too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's rare for people to say "sixteen o'clock". Many people would be more likely to convert the time to 12-hour clock and say "four PM" out loud.

It's common to read out 24-hour times that end in 00 as "hundred".

- 16:00 - "sixteen hundred"
- 16:45 - "sixteen forty-five"
- 16:05 - "sixteen oh-five"

Sometimes, you hear something like "sixteen hundred *hours*". This is sometimes described as "military time". It sounds illogical, but it is commonly understood.

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, 0400 is *o four hundred hours*. 1600 is *sixteen hundred hours*. No one says *sixteen o'clock*. Otherwise, much as Slim says.

Comment: Interesting, I think of "x hundred hours" mostly an American thing.

Comment: @slim: And, as you say, military. On reflection, I think you're right though. We're just as likely to say 'o four hundred' and 'sixteen hundred', if it's clear that it's time we're talking about.