# Representing the time of day

Tags: time

> If you apply after 1200 hr (Monday to Friday), or on Saturdays, Sundays and Public Holidays, you can collect your cashier's order after 1200 hr on the next business day.

Dear users, I saw the above statement on a bank website which instructs its customers on when to collect their pre-paid cashier's orders. I found their use of "1200 hr" very  strange. Actually, I mistook it as 12 hrs (a duration) at first. I wonder if representing the time of day as "#### hr" is conventionally accepted in formal context? Does it convey the exact same meaning as "12:00"? Thank you.

Comment: [Related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35006/how-should-one-say-times-aloud-in-24-hour-notation) The first answer mentions how it is pronounced, in your case _twelve-hundred hours_.

Comment: It's a little non-standard, at least in the US.  As mentioned by JJJ, it would be read as "twelve-hundred hours", which is "military" terminology meaning 12 noon, or 12:00 pm.

Comment: You have the option to use the label “hours.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How To Read Military Time](https://www.militarytime.us/how-to-prononce-read-military-time/)

a quick and simple primer ... with annunciations.

ps: will not help with '0 dark thirty' though.