# Time of a day in a scientific article

Tags: time

I am writing a scientific article and have a question regarding the time of day. I am using the the system without a.m. and p.m.. So I have time of days like: 9:00, 15:00 (3 p.m.) and 23:00 (11 p.m.). If I want to adress a certain time can I use 'o'clock' like:
"From 16 o’clock – 19 o’clock"

Or how would you do that?

Comment: "16:00 hours" might be more appropriate than "16 o' clock".

Comment: Just write the times - "from 16:00 to 19:00".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: Nobody uses the 24 hour clock format with "o'clock".

Comment: Rather than o'clock one refers to 16:00 as sixteen hundred hours.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Such questions are largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization. or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answer :-)

Comment: As an aside, the term "o'clock" (meaning "of the clock" or "on the clock") came to refer to the face of a clock with 12 numbers.  In Middle English and later colloquial use, o or o' can be an abbreviation of "on" or "of".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should one say times aloud in 24-hour notation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35006/how-should-one-say-times-aloud-in-24-hour-notation)